# Web - Disable Android Notification Bar Audio/Video Controls

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, video

Does anyone know how to disable Chrome/Android's pull down notification bar video controls?

I have a background video in my HTML but I don't want the audio notification to appear since the video is already muted and has controls off?

It's just a background video so it needs no notification of control or sound.

I hope this is understandable. Maybe it's not possible due to the need to control websites with audio.. Even though my video doesn't actually have any!

HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline>
   <source src="my video src" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
#video-background {
  /*  making the video fullscreen  */
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Same question. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Sadly not, still looking!